# Client-Server application on different computers

Tags: java, networking

I want to modify my code to make the clients connect to the server if the server is hosted on a different machine. This is the code I have now:

Server:

```
int port = 5000;
ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(port);
Socket socket = server.accept();
output/input streams....
```

Client:

```
String host = "localhost";
int port = 5000;
Socket socket = new Socket(host, port);
OutputStream out = socket.getOutputStream();
InputStream in = socket.getInputStream();
```

I am aware of the inetAddress and that's what I need help with, I don't know how to use it correctly, I don't want any complicated methods just enough to connect them together. Also I want to know if it is possible to use DNS for this or if I need a web server or something similar (of course DNS is purely curiosity).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To connect to a remote machine you need that machines IP address or hostname, then you can use [InetAddress.getByName(String)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/net/InetAddress.html#getByName%28java.lang.String%29).

You'd use the IP address if there's no [DNS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System) server available to resolve the IP from the hostname, like this:

```
Socket socket = new Socket(InetAddress.getByName("1.2.3.4"), 5000);
```

Or is there's is a DNS server, then you can just pass the servers hostname like this:

```
Socket socket = new Socket(InetAddress.getByName("myserver"), 5000);
```